# Cocalc for Python, can't find csv files to read into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a file into a pandas dataframe and I get a file not found error.

1. Find the path

```
import os
print('Get current working directory :      ', os.getcwd())
print('Get current file name :    ', "iris.csv")
```

I get this:
Get current working directory :       /home/user/test
Get current file name :     iris.csv

2. try to load:

I have tried the following

```
iris = pd.read_csv("test/iris.csv")
iris = pd.read_csv("home/user/test/iris.csv")
iris = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Try this `iris = pd.read_csv("./iris.csv")`

Comment: no love, it didn't work :-(

Comment: What do you get when copying the path of iris.csv? (Shift and right click on windows and I think alt and right click for Mac)

Comment: Thanks-- the issue was I needed to capitalize Iris

Comment: By default the filesystem on Linux computers (e.g., CoCalc where you were working) is case sensitive, unlike Windows and MacOS.